# Not able to connect to wi-fi on Ubuntu in KVM

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

My primary OS is arch Linux.
I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on KVM. But only wired network option is available there. When I head over to wi-fi it is displaying network adapter is not available. I am not able to connect to internet So reinstall option is not available. I have tried many Linux ditributions but problem is existed on every single distro. Any ideas what I should probably do?

While creating new virtual machine there are 5 options in network selection in KVM. I selected Virtual network 'default': NAT (inactive) and Host device wlp3s0: macvtap. But both seems to be not working.

1. Virtual network 'default': NAT (inactive)
2. Host device enp2s0 : macvtap
3. Host device tun0: macvtap
4. Host device wlp3s0: macvtap
5. Specify shared device name

Comment: https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Networking might help.  Usually, unless the KVM has direct access to the Wifi card, it should use the  wired network.

Answer (score 3):

KVM virtualizes network devices. Even if your host machine (the physical one) is connected to WiFi, KVM will virtualize it internally as an Ethernet device. As far as I know, no virtualization solution virtualizes a Wireless adapter into another Wireless adapter.

If you want internet access on your VM, firstly ensure that your host machine has internet access (either via WiFi or Ethernet) and then choose the NAT mode in KVM. Also ensure that the link state is set to **Active**. Once you start up your VM, you should see a LAN connection established and you should be able to access the internet.